# Android Studio: Progress Bar without thread or multiprocessing

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Hi everyone this is my first post on stackoverflow, I have a very specific question about Android Studio. I would like to implement a method that allows me to start a Progressbar-wait several seconds before it is finished-and end it.

I would like to create this method without using threads or MultiProcessing.

I'm not a real expert in java and I can't figure out why my method doesn't work/doesn't compile!

This is the code of method:

```
    public void RunProgressBar(){
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < progressBar.getMax()){
            progressBar.setProgress(counter);
            SystemClock.sleep(200);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

The method is used in:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.RunProgressBar();
}
```

In case I also added all the code of the MainActivity

```
package com.xedoll.green_player;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.RunProgressBar();
    }

    public void RunProgressBar(){
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < progressBar.getMax()){
            progressBar.setProgress(counter);
            SystemClock.sleep(200);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick comment - in Java, methods start with lowercase letters, this means that your method RunProgressBar() should be named runProgressBar(). This is a convention and following them normally makes code more readable.

The problem here is that you are trying to call RunProgressBar() on an instance of a ProgressBar. Your custom method RunProgressBar() belongs to the MainActivity class. This means that the line `progressBar.RunProgressBar()` should be changed to `RunProgressBar()`, or `this.RunProgressBar()`.

The second issue I see is that you are implementing View.OnClickListener, but you don't `@Override` the method `public void onClick(View v)`.

After sorting this the code should compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot E.Makarovas!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks EMakarovas for your help and your advice, it works!
I reinvented the method to make it work on almost any progressbar!

Here is the code for those who need it!

```
public void runProgressBar(ProgressBar p, int delay){
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < p.getMax()){
            p.setProgress(counter);
            SystemClock.sleep(delay);
            counter++;
        }
}
```